# vue cli image src with aframe not work

Tags: webpack, vue.js, aframe, vue-cli

I have developed a project created with vue-cli

The basic sample works:

```
<img src=“./assets/panorama1.jpg”>
```

But when I use it with a-frame it doesn't work:

```
<a-sky src=“./assets/panorama1.jpg”></a-sky>
```

It can't find the image.

The following is the webpack setting:

```
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
  '@': resolve('src'),
}
```

I must use

```
require('./assets/panorama1.jpg') 
// or
require('@/assets/panorama1.jpg')
```

or

```
import panoramaImage from './assets/panorama1.jpg'
// or
import panoramaImage from '@/assets/panorama1.jpg'
```

then set it in Vue's data so it can work.

What's the problem?

Comment: What is `<a-sky>` ?. Is it a component you built or provided by third party library

Comment: `a-sky` is aframe library's pimitive which will convert to canvas inside `a-scene`. Aframe use to build webVR application. I'm really not sure it's aframe or webpack setting's problem. https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/primitives/a-sky.html

Answer (score 0):

You could get image from a computed method which gives you the image from a require:

```
<template>
  <img :id="panoramaId" :src="panoramaImage" />
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'PanoramaAsset',
  props: ['panorama'],
  computed: {
    panoramaId () {
      return `panorama${this.panorama.id}`
    },
    panoramaImage () {
      return require(`@/assets/panoramas/panorama-${this.panorama.id}.jpg`)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Buddy, you saved my life! But so far, isn't there a better option? I have like a list of assets and it doesn't seem reasonable to create a plethora of computed props...